# Can we use element of Iframe (HTML/JS) / Umap

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, queryselector

I make a test HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 99vh;padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <head>
        <title>Exemple de carte uMap intégrée à une page Web</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="height: 99vh; padding: 0px;margin: 0px;">
        <div style="height: 99vh; padding: 0px;margin: 0px;">
<iframe id="test" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/fr/map/etudes-de-lignes_447095?scaleControl=true&miniMap=false&scrollWheelZoom=true&zoomControl=true&allowEdit=false&moreControl=true&searchControl=true&tilelayersControl=null&embedControl=null&datalayersControl=null&onLoadPanel=databrowser&captionBar=false&datalayers=1269884%2C1279150%2C1269879%2C1269864%2C1269877%2C1269867%2C1252607%2C1252582%2C1252709%2C1252620%2C1252484%2C1295498%2C1294338%2C1294480%2C1294294%2C1294089%2C1294063%2C1294036%2C1294048%2C1252517%2C1294231%2C1289668%2C1294219%2C1289680%2C1294120%2C1289701%2C1289482%2C1269860%2C1289520%2C1269851%2C1289609%2C1294019%2C1247352%2C1269847%2C1252954%2C1252588%2C1268352%2C1279119%2C1247146%2C1247202%2C1247216%2C1252960%2C1247245%2C1247236%2C1247177%2C1247192%2C1247171%2C1247253%2C1252953%2C1268409%2C1252570%2C1252557%2C1252551%2C1252486%2C1268443%2C1252949%2C1247129%2C1252942%2C1252804%2C1269852%2C1269859%2C1269861"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to use some script like document.querySelector, but iframe hide all classes..

Example : `document.querySelector('#test').contentWindow.querySelector('.umap-close-link')`

Error : `DOMException: "Permission denied to access property "querySelector" on cross-origin object"`

Can i have some solution plz ?

Sorry for my english :)

### EDIT

Nice, thank you.

In the original URL https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/fr/map/etudes-de-lignes_447095  i can acess to the querySelector easy.

Can i do some extensions (or other things) to make personnalizable content ?

Comment: The exception has already told you that that is not possible.  XSS from javascript from one domain to another is a browser enforced security policy.

Comment: Like @Taplar just said you can't run scripts inside an iframe from another domain. What you can do is to create a copy of that iframe by reading its html content and then modifying that copy, but unless you replace the previous iframe with the modified one, you will not see any changes on your screen.

Comment: @Gabriel Azevedo Nice, how i can read html content on iframe, do u have example ? thx